# Find Duplicate/Repeated or Unique words spanning across multiple lines in a file

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep, regular-expression

### Problem

Is it possible to print repeated words that are not unique and spanning across multiple lines? not just unique words within singular lines.

### Previous work

There's [this](https://superuser.com/a/843906/1138232) question which solves the problem of finding duplicate words within the **same line**. It also has an issue that it matches the ending *word boundary* with the starting one.

### Sample Input

```
[
    {
        entity: 
        {
            id: int
            employee:
            {
                id: int
                company: {
                    name: string
                    area: 
                    {
                        country: string
                        city: string
                        zipcode: string
                    }
                }
                person: 
                {
                    id: int
                    firstName: string
                    middleName: string
                    lastName: string
                }
            }
        }
        entity: 
        {
            id: int
            person: 
            {
                id: int
                firstName: string
                middleName: string
                lastName: string
            }
            area: 
            {
                country: string
                city: string
                zipcode: string
            }
        }
    }
]
```

### Sample Output -- REPEATED/DUPLICATE

```
area
city
country
entity
firstName
id
int
lastName
middleName
person
string
zipcode
```

### Sample Output -- UNIQUE

```
company
employee
name
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it stand-alone, including a MCVE with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. It's trivial to print unique or duplicated words from a block of multi-line text but the question you reference was trying to find contiguous repetitions of the same word which is a harder problem - is that what this questions is about? How to do that when the word is repeated on the next line instead of on the same line?

Comment: FWIW [I just added an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1523995/1089278) to [the question you reference](https://superuser.com/a/843906/1138232) showing how to remove repeated words from multi-line text.

Comment: Edited my answer providing an example input and output.

Comment: I think may have misunderstood the word "repeated" in the previous question. They were looking to identify a word like `dog` repeated in a string like `the dog dog barked`, not just the word `dog` duplicated anywhere in the input (e.g. `the dog barked at another dog`). Finding duplicate or unique words in a block of text is trivial, it's finding repeated words that's interesting and removing the repetition that's actually relatively difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

#### grep

```
grep -wo "[[:alnum:]]\+" input_file.txt | sort | uniq [-c | -d | -u]
```

#### egrep (permits regex meta-characters without escaping them)

```
egrep -wo "[[:alnum:]]+" input_file.txt | sort | uniq [-c | -d | -u]
```

## Explanation

1. First you can tokenize the words with `grep -wo`, each word is printed on a singular line.
2. Then you can sort the tokenized words with `sort`.
3. Finally can find consecutive unique or duplicate words with `uniq`.

   3.1. `uniq -c` This prints the words and their count. Covering all matched words -- duplicate and unique.

   3.2. `uniq -d` This prints all duplicate words.

   3.3. `uniq -u` This prints all unique words.

## Examples

### Sample Input

```
abc line 1
xyz zzz
123 456
abc end line
```

#### Example 1 -- duplicate/unique words with their count:

```bsh
grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]\+' input_file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
   1 1
   1 123
   1 456
   2 abc
   1 end
   2 line
   1 xyz
   1 zzz
```

#### Example 2 -- duplicate words only:

```bsh
grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]\+' infile | sort | uniq -d
```

Output:

```
abc
line
```

#### Example 3 -- unique words only:

```bsh
grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]\+' infile | sort | uniq -u
```

Output

```
1
123
456
end
xyz
zzz
```

## Command Dissection & Sources

- `grep` parameters

  - [`-w`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control) tokenizes whole words separated by word boundaries (non-word characters `\W`)
  - [`-o`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control) prints only the matched non-empty parts of matching line -- i.e. in our case prints the matched non-empty words only within the matched line
- `grep` regex expression

  - [`[[:alnum:]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) Alphanumeric cahracters
  - [`\+`](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/FiniteAutomata/Section07/sect07_19.html) Kleene Plus character. Matches one or more occurrence.
- [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html)
- [`uniq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Uniq-Program.html)

  - `-c` Prints words with their repetition count.
  - `-d` Prints only repeated (duplicated) lines.
  - `-u` Prints only nonrepeated (unique) lines.

Comment: None of that finds just repeated words as in [the the other other question](https://superuser.com/questions/843778/find-repeated-words-in-a-text/843906#843906) that you reference in your question.

Comment: I'm talking about finding a repeated keyword within the entire file regardless if consecutive or not. Edited my question and self-answer.